# Searching for Three Strings within a Cell Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search through a column of cells for one of three strings.  If none of the three strings are found I want to copy the current entire row and paste it in a new sheet in the next empty row. Here is my code that is giving me issues. I believe the error is where I define the string for comparison. I already created the new sheet.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
Dim text As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text3 As String
Dim NextRow As Integer
text = InputBox("Enter PLUS Name")
text2 = InputBox("Enter HERO Name")
text3 = InputBox("Enter Outboard Motor Plan Name")
For n = LastRow To 2 Step -1

   If InStr(1, Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)).Value, text Or text2    Or text3, vbTextCompare = 1) = 0 Then

        Rows(n).EntireRow.Copy
        Worksheets("Vendor Paid").Activate
        NextRow = Sheets("Vendor Paid").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Rows(NextRow).EntireRow.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Activate
        Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: For some reason I've had enough of incessantly editing my answer. So I'm going to add here that you shouldn't bother with the Integer variable type unless you want to restrict the value of a variable. It's (probably unnoticeably) slower than Long and Excel just uses a Long in the background anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)).Value, text Or text2    Or text3, vbTextCompare = 1) = 0 Then
```

To:

```
If InStr(1, Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)).Value, text, vbTextCompare) < 1 And _
   InStr(1, Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)).Value, text2, vbTextCompare) < 1 And _
   InStr(1, Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)).Value, text3, vbTextCompare) < 1 Then
```

The expression `text Or text2 Or text3` causes an error because `Or` is a logical operator and tries to treat the variables `text`, `text2` and `text3` as boolean values. If it can't turn them into boolean values it will complain.

Additionally, `vbTextCompare = 1` will evaluate to True, which has a numerical value of -1. Entering this as the third argument to `InStr` is invalid; `InStr` will only accept 0, 1, or 2 here. `vbTextCompare` is a variable with the value 1, `vbBinaryCompare` is a variable with the value 0, and `vbDatabaseCompare` holds the value 2.

Also, I suggest you change the following:

```
Rows(n).EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Vendor Paid").Activate
NextRow = Sheets("Vendor Paid").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Rows(NextRow).EntireRow.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Activate
Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

To:

```
With Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting")
    .Rows(.Range("A:A").End(xlUp).Row+1).Value = Worksheets("Vendor Paid").rows(n).value
End With
Worksheets("Vendor Paid").Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete
```

Just a note: I'd suggest using Option Explicit at the top of your code module. Simply go right up to the top of your module and type (on it's own line) Option Explicit. This means that you can't use variables without first declaring them, like you appear to have done with n.

Welcome to SO, by the way :). Your question is totally ok, but it'll help you get answers if you do the following:

1. Indicate which line your error occurs on
2. Tell us what the error message is
3. Cut your code down as much as you can while still reproducing the problem (less for people to do to help you!)

There's a lot of information here, if you have any questions I encourage you to ask in the comments :). Also, use the Immediate window (Ctrl+G from the editor) to evaluate some of the things I've told you. Try entering `? vbTextCompare = 1` and press enter to see what the result is. Or emulate your second argument to InStr: `? "a" Or "b" Or "c"` to see what happens when you use `Or` with strings.

**EDIT**

When your error occurs, hit debug. Then, bring up the immediate window by pressing ctrl+g. Now try entering the following lines, one at a time, and pressing enter:

```
? Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting") Is Nothing
? Cells(n, 6) Is Nothing
? Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)) Is Nothing
```

An error should occur for at least two of those lines, let me know which one it is.

**With statement**

The with statement is used when you will be predominantly accessing methods and properties of a single object in your code. That object is specified after the keyword `With`. Then, you can access that object's methods and properties without using it's name. A basic example:

```
' We are working with the Spiff Download Reporting sheet
With Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting")
    'Because we've used the With statement we don't need to
    'specify the target object's name each time we access a
    'property (e.g. the name) or method of that object
    MsgBox(.Name) 
End With
' End with is essentially stating that we are no longer
' predominantly working with the object we specified
' earlier
```

Comment: I would add a fourth item to the list: upvote answers that are helpful, and accept the best answer that solves your issue.

Comment: I was directing my comment at Eric. I thought your answer was excellent and he hasn't upvoted or accepted it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I divide up my InStr statements I am getting an object defined error for the entire If statement.

Comment: I am confused by your with loop. I haven't had much experience with those. Could you explain it in pseudo for me?

Comment: @HeadofCatering yeah I got it, I was making a joke about actually adding it to the list. And thanking you for appreciating my answer :).

Comment: @EricKearney I've added and edit to the bottom of my question to try to solve your error. I'll add another one now to explain `With`.

Comment: Only the second line gave an error.  The error was Compile Error: Expected:=. When you say immediate window do you mean the module where my code is? By the way, thanks for explaining the with statement.

Comment: Do you have the underscores at the end of the first and second lines of the if statement, like in the answer? The immediate window is like a console where you can interrogate variables live. Press Ctrl+g when you're in the editor and it'll pop up (I've now noticed my answer says Alt+g, sorry!)

Comment: I used the immediate window as you said.  I got "False" for the first two statements and I got "Application or object defined error" for the last statement.

Comment: What're the values of `Worksheets("Spiff Download Reporting").Range(Cells(n, 6)` and `text3` at the time when that error occurs?